# How to make Windows 10 Store "forget" an app download for testing purposes?

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-10, windows-store

I'm testing my Win32 app converted to UWP, so I'm new to the whole Windows 10 Store concept.

So far I was able to get my app certified & published in the store via a private link. Now I would like to download and test it, but there's an issue.

The first time someone sees the app it has the following options:

[image]

but once you get it, all you see is this:

[image]

and even if you log in under a different Microsoft account (on the same computer), or previously uninstall the app, you get this:

[image]

and "free trial" simply installs it w/o a trial in that case.

So my question is, how do I make Windows Store "forget" that I have this app?

Comment: This can't be done and to remove apps from the accoun is 1 of the most asked request in the feedback hub app

Comment: @magicandre1981: hah, that's pretty stupid! Thanks for confirming. So what do you guys do to test your app's store integration?

Comment: @magicandre1981: me too. But do you know that Microsoft now allows to add Win32 or .NET apps to the store as well? That's what I'm doing it for.

Comment: yes, I know what it is and for testing I installed Kodi via store but see no value in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have bought the app you can't undo that, but you can always create a new user who has never bought for the testing purpose.

EDIT: Windows Store is for real transactions and not for testing. If you want to test, you should have a custom build that uses [CurrentAppSimulator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator.aspx) instead of [CurrentApp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.aspx)

Comment: you mean Windows user account? I just tried it with a local account and it had the same result.

Comment: Plus, even if it worked, how many user accounts will it take? I don't run my tests just once :)

Comment: Well does Sony goes to the shop and buys TVs to test them? No, shop is not for testing. I have updated the answer on how to do the testing.

Comment: I'm doing this for a Win32/UWP app (Anniversary Update, Windows 10 v.1607 or later) that uses `Windows.Services.Store` namespace and not `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store`. I didn't see that it supported `AppSimulator`?

Comment: You can use CurrentAppSImulator, however you will probably need to rewrite some code. But if you expect to frequently test this, I don't see any other way.