# How to combine RegisterDragDrop, RoInitialize to work together in one thread?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com, windows-runtime

I have a dilemma. My GUI-based C++ app requires to implement drag-and-drop functionality. At the same time, I'm converting this Win32 app to [UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide) to submit to Windows Store. But there's one issue:

To implement drag-and-drop I need to call these two methods:

```
OleInitialize(NULL);
//...
HRESULT hr = RegisterDragDrop(hMainWnd, pDropTarget);
```

and to init WinRT stuff to work with Windows Store, I need to call:

```
HRESULT hr = RoInitialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED);
```

Unfortunately [`OleInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690134(v=vs.85).aspx) initialized COM as `single-thread apartment` and [`RoInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br224650(v=vs.85).aspx) requires multi-threaded model, while [`RegisterDragDrop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405(v=vs.85).aspx) cannot function without calling `OleInitialize`.

Any idea how to resolve it? (apart from moving `RoInitialize` and all WinRT code into a worker thread, that will complicate things.)

Comment: this is may be incorrect but with next code drag-drop still worked ok `if (0 <= OleInitialize(0)) CoUninitialize(); RoInitialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED);` - yes unpaired calls - `OleInitialize` with `CoUninitialize`.

Comment: @RbMm: Hmm, yeah, it seems to work. Thanks. Although, can you please explain what you're doing there?

Comment: RegisterDragDrop is not available in UWP so you're already off on the wrong foot. For UWP use CoreDragDropManager.TargetRequested.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Sorry, Raymond, but you're incorrect. I have my Win10 Store converted UWP app and `RegisterDragDrop` works just fine in it. Can you explain though, why RbMm's solution works?

Comment: @c00000fd: You're talking about Project Centennial right?  And you have a hybrid Win32-UWP app, but using the user32.dll GUI, not the UWP GUI?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, I'm talking about the Project Centennial app.

Comment: @c00000fd - `OleInitialize(p)={CoInitialize(p);SomeOleInitCode();}` as result `OleInitialize(0);CoUninitialize();` have same effect as call `SomeOleInitCode();` after this we can call `CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED )` without `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`. so finally we have almost same effect like `OleInitialize(0)` but in multithreaded apartment. but **OLE operations are not thread-safe** - so this is how minimum very dangerous do this. hower if use only DragDrop (from Ole features) and only in single thread - may work

Comment: @c00000fd - i not familiar with `UWP` but think exist way detect `UWP` at runtime. so code must be next `HRESULT hr = IsUWPApp() ? RoInitialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED) : OleInitialize(0);` also if some API not exported in platform - think you need use `/DELAYLOAD:ole32.dll`, etc - for resolve only present functions call . think this is will be best solution

Comment: @RbMm: Why do you assume, that Raymond Chen were interested in a bug in [some developer's code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41008037/1889329)? As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx) one must not call `DestroyWindow` from `DllMain`. This developer did. They need to fix their code. It's disturbing, that you believe, that someone else should take action.

Comment: @RbMm: The document [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx) explains, that *"you should never [...] call functions in User32.dll or Gdi32.dll [from within DllMain]."* [DestroyWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682.aspx) is a function in User32.dll.

Comment: @IInspectable - ok, really here kernel of problem in call `CoUninitialize` from DllMain, but probably you right - this is not interesting. i delete own comments about this. and really code already long time ago fixed. you not understand me

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that Centennial called itself UWP. Can you `RoInitialize(RO_INIT_SINGLETHREADED)`? UI threads should not be MTA. (By the way, the OleInitialize+CoUninitalize trick is not a good idea. You rip the COM rug out from under OLE and everything is a mess.)

Comment: @RaymondChen: Are you sure about `RO_INIT_SINGLETHREADED`? WinRT uses a lot of asynchronous calls (see the code in my answer.) I can try it. But it usually takes several days for the app to go through Store certification process.

Answer (score 2):

[Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) in his usual condescending way is pretty good at criticizing things but offers no fix to an existing problem. I'm posting this mostly for later self-reference and in case someone else stumbles upon the same issue as well. I just spent several days trying to resolve this bug, so maybe it will save time for someone else.

## Problem

First off, this is a native Win32 code (no `.NET` or `C++/CX`.) It is `C++` with a sprinkle of [WRL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438466.aspx) for easier handling of `WinRT`/`COM` stuff.

In my case I have a Win32 GUI app that implements *drag-and-drop* of files into its main window. So to init it, one needs to do this from the main thread, right when the app starts:

```
OleInitialize(NULL);
//...
HRESULT hr = RegisterDragDrop(hMainWnd, pDropTarget);
```

The [`OleInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690134(v=vs.85).aspx) call above will initialize COM for the main thread to use `single-thread apartment`, which is required for [`RegisterDragDrop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405(v=vs.85).aspx) to succeed. Without it, the *drag-and-drop* function will not work.

Then, say you decide to convert this `Win32` app to `UWP` using Microsoft's [Project Centennial](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop) converter for inclusion into Windows 10 store.

When the app is converted and listed in the store under their trial-license scheme, you will employ the following logic to check if the user has a trial or an activated (i.e. purchased) copy of the app. You'll begin it as such:

```
//Init COM for WinRT
RoInitialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED);

ComPtr<IStoreContextStatics> pStoreContextStatics;
if(SUCCEEDED(RoGetActivationFactory(
    HStringReference(L"Windows.Services.Store.StoreContext").Get(), 
    __uuidof(pStoreContextStatics), 
    &pStoreContextStatics)) &&
    pStoreContextStatics)
{
    //Get store context for the app
    ComPtr<IStoreContext> pStoreContext;
    if(SUCCEEDED(pStoreContextStatics->GetDefault(&pStoreContext)) &&
        pStoreContext)
    {
        //Got store context
        //....

    }
}
```

and then if you need to know trial vs. activated status of the app, using [this logic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/monetize/implement-a-trial-version-of-your-app), you'd call:

```
ComPtr<IAsyncOperation<StoreAppLicense*>> p_opAppLic;
if(SUCCEEDED(pStoreContext->GetAppLicenseAsync(p_opAppLic)) &&
    p_opAppLic)
{
    ComPtr<IAsyncOperationCompletedHandler<StoreAppLicense*>> p_onAppLicCallback =
        Callback<Implements<RuntimeClassFlags<ClassicCom>, IAsyncOperationCompletedHandler<StoreAppLicense*>, FtmBase>>(
        [](IAsyncOperation<StoreAppLicense*>* pOp, AsyncStatus status)
    {
        if (status == AsyncStatus::Completed)
        {
            ComPtr<IStoreAppLicense> pAppLicResult;
            if(SUCCEEDED(pOp->GetResults(&pAppLicResult)) &&
                pAppLicResult)
            {
                BYTE nActive = -1;
                BYTE nTrial = -1;
                pAppLicResult->get_IsActive(&nActive);
                pAppLicResult->get_IsTrial(&nTrial);

                //Get app's store ID with SKU
                HString strStoreId;
                pAppLicResult->get_SkuStoreId(strStoreId.GetAddressOf());

                if(nActive == 1 &&
                    nTrial == 0)
                {
                    //Activated, or purchased copy
                }
                else if(nActive == 1 &&
                    nTrial == 1)
                {
                    //Trial copy
                }
                else
                {
                    //Error -- store returned some gibberish
                }
            }
        }

        return S_OK;
    });

    if(SUCCEEDED(p_opAppLic->put_Completed(p_onAppLicCallback.Get())))
    {
        //Success initiating async call
    }
}
```

So, if you do all this, your UWP-converted app will behave in a very strange way. Here's an example. Say a user purchases a license for the app thru Windows Store. In turn your app logic calls the code above to see if the app is activated, but what you get back is `nActive=0` and `nTrial=1`. Then if you check `strStoreId` it will be your app store ID but without the SKU. WTF!?

I know, it's really confusing. As an aside, let me explain. When you first list your app in a Windows Store it will be assigned a Store ID. Something like: `ABCDEFG12345`. Then if you submit any follow-up update(s) to the first version of the same app, they will add a `SKU` number to it, that will make the whole app ID change to `ABCDEFG12345/0010`, then `ABCDEFG12345/0011` for the next update, and so on.

Well, the WinRT code above would return my app store ID as `ABCDEFG12345` without any `SKU` attached to it. Which was wrong, since it was a third or so update to the first version of the app. And thus any additional attributes for that app store ID were also wrong.

So that was the issue that I was faced with...

## Cause

All the headache that I described above was caused by my omission to check the result code returned from the first `RoInitialize` call. I would be able to catch the problem much faster if I did this:

```
//Init COM for WinRT
if(FAILED(RoInitialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED)))
{
    //WinRT COM initialization failed
    //Go scratch your head why....
}
```

In this case `RoInitialize` will fail with error code `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`. The [documentation for it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br224650(v=vs.85).aspx) is as helpful as Windows Help (F1) option:

> A previous call to RoInitialize specified the concurrency model for
>   this thread as multithread apartment (MTA). This could also indicate
>   that a change from neutral-threaded apartment to single-threaded
>   apartment has occurred.

What previous call? The only parameter anyone can call it with is [RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br224661(v=vs.85).aspx).

So I started digging deeper and by the process of elimination found that the `OleInitialize` call earlier was the reason why `RoInitialize` failed and caused the cascade of events that I described above.

Thus I was at the point of asking the question here.

Note on the side, that the **bug ridden** WinRT library ([ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201201/how-to-get-expiration-date-for-a-trial-license-for-an-app-published-in-the-windo), [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40209789/offlinelicenseschanged-event-is-never-raised-when-trial-license-expires-for-a-wi), [ref3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164251/error-message-when-trying-to-start-an-expired-trial-uwp-app-downloaded-from-the), [ref4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354594/how-to-properly-wait-for-asynchronous-winrt-callback-functions-to-stop), [ref5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119090/how-to-make-windows-10-store-forget-an-app-download-for-testing-purposes)) gave me no indications of a problem in all the calls following `RoInitialize` and somewhere internally silently failed to retrieve the app's `SKU` because of a `single-thread apartment` COM initialization.

## Hack/Workaround

As was suggested by [RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401656/rbmm) in the comments above, doing the following will work, but is a totally undocumented behavior:

```
if(SUCCEEDED(OleInitialize(0))
{
    CoUninitialize();
}

CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
```

So if you don't want your app to start crashing for no apparent reason, I would not use it.

## Solution

My solution that I went with was to move all the `WinRT COM` stuff (code I listed above: 2nd and 3rd code segments) into a separate worker thread. It will work fine from there. The issue is *marshalling* calls between your main thread and this worker thread. It is doable, but requires some work, i.e. using `mutexes` and `events` for synchronized access, etc.

So if anyone finds an easier fix for this, please post your solution. I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: You don't need mutexes and events to marshal WinRT interfaces across apartment boundaries. As explained under [Threading and Marshaling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh771042.aspx), *"in the vast majority of cases, instances of Windows Runtime classes, like standard C++ objects, can be accessed from any thread. Such classes are referred to as 'agile'."*

Comment: (Note: this might be inaccurate.) He did offer a solution, `CoreDragDropManager`. `RegisterDragDrop()` still works in your converted app package because it's not using any Windows Runtime/UWP features. The Desktop App Converter just made an AppX bundle around your still-Win32-only desktop app. Now that you are using Windows Runtime/UWP features, you need `RoInitialize()` and the `RegisterDragDrop()` no longer applies.

Comment: @andlabs: Well, maybe `CoreDragDropManager.RegisterDragDrop` would work in a Win32 app converted to UWP. You see, the reason I'm using this conversion process is so that my app can still work in OS prior to Windows 10 as well. Plus just giving me `CoreDragDropManager.TargetRequested` would require several hours of researching, learning and trying it out without a concrete example. So the question is why abandon `RegisterDragDrop`? Just to compensate for something else.

Comment: My question then is why do you need to use `RoInitialize()` — what parts of the Windows Runtime/UWP do you need?

Answer (score 1):

solution to the IDsObjPicker crashes I mentioned in the comment ealier, quick code I wrote just now.

Use code below as:

```
  TDsObjPicker lv_PickInfo;

  memset(&lv_PickInfo, 0, sizeof(TDsObjPicker));

  Sec_InitDsObjPicker(&lv_PickInfo, &lv_InitInfo);

  Sec_InvokeDsObjPicker(&lv_PickInfo, 0, &lv_oData);
```

Solution is to run the dialog in another thread and init the thread without the Ole+Com combination:

```
// command codes
#define DSOPCMD_EXITTHREAD   1
#define DSOPCMD_INITIALIZE   2
#define DSOPCMD_INVOKE       3



// parameters of object picker via thread
typedef struct tagDsObjPicker
{
  // thread handle
  HANDLE          hThread;

  // events
  HANDLE          hCmdEvt;
  HANDLE          hRdyEvt;

  // commands
  UINT            CmdCode;
  HRESULT         hResult;

  // command parameters - DSOPCMD_INITIALIZE
  DSOP_INIT_INFO *InitInfo;

  // command parameters - DSOPCMD_INVOKE
  HWND            hWnd;
  IDataObject   **oData;

  //
} TDsObjPicker;




DWORD CALLBACK _Sec_DsObjPickerThread(VOID *in_Param)
{
    /* locals */
    HRESULT          lv_hCreateResult;
    HRESULT          lv_hResult;
    TDsObjPicker    *lv_PickInfo;
    IDsObjectPicker *lv_oPicker;


  // get info structure
  lv_PickInfo = (TDsObjPicker*)in_Param;

  // init COM
  CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

  // preclear object pointer
  lv_oPicker = NULL;

  // create instance of picker
  lv_hCreateResult = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_DsObjectPicker, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IDsObjectPicker, (VOID**)&lv_oPicker);

  // while thread is not aborted
  while (lv_PickInfo->CmdCode != DSOPCMD_EXITTHREAD)
  {
    // wait for command event
    if (WaitForSingleObject(lv_PickInfo->hCmdEvt, INFINITE) == 0)
    {
      // what command?
      switch (lv_PickInfo->CmdCode)
      {
        // call init
        case DSOPCMD_INITIALIZE:
        {
          // call object
          if (lv_hCreateResult)
            lv_hResult = lv_hCreateResult;
          else
            lv_hResult = lv_oPicker->Initialize(lv_PickInfo->InitInfo);

          // done
          break;
        }

        // call invoke
        case DSOPCMD_INVOKE:
        {
          // call object
          if (lv_hCreateResult)
            lv_hResult = lv_hCreateResult;
          else
            lv_hResult = lv_oPicker->InvokeDialog(lv_PickInfo->hWnd, lv_PickInfo->oData);

          // done
          break;
        }

        // other command codes
        default:
          lv_hResult = E_FAIL;
          break;
      }

      // store result
      lv_PickInfo->hResult = lv_hResult;

      // notify caller
      SetEvent(lv_PickInfo->hRdyEvt);
    }
  }

  // destroy the picker object
  if (lv_oPicker)
    lv_oPicker->Release();

  // cleanup COM
  CoUninitialize();

  // leave the thread
  return 0;
}



VOID Sec_DoneDsObjPicker(TDsObjPicker *in_PickInfo)
{
  // is thread created?
  if (in_PickInfo->hThread)
  {
    // set command code
    in_PickInfo->CmdCode = DSOPCMD_EXITTHREAD;

    // trigger the thread to process the code
    SetEvent(in_PickInfo->hCmdEvt);

    // wait for thread to finish
    WaitForSingleObject(in_PickInfo->hThread, INFINITE);

    // close thread handle
    CloseHandle(in_PickInfo->hThread);
  }

  // close event handles
  if (in_PickInfo->hCmdEvt) CloseHandle(in_PickInfo->hCmdEvt);
  if (in_PickInfo->hRdyEvt) CloseHandle(in_PickInfo->hRdyEvt);

  // clear
  memset(in_PickInfo, 0, sizeof(TDsObjPicker));
}




HRESULT Sec_InitDsObjPicker(TDsObjPicker *in_PickInfo, DSOP_INIT_INFO *in_InitInfo)
{
    /* locals */
    DWORD lv_TID;


  // thread not yet created?
  if (!in_PickInfo->hThread)
  {
    // create events
    in_PickInfo->hCmdEvt = CreateEvent(0,0,0,0);
    in_PickInfo->hRdyEvt = CreateEvent(0,0,0,0);

    // if ok
    if (in_PickInfo->hCmdEvt && in_PickInfo->hRdyEvt)
    {
      // create the thread
      in_PickInfo->hThread = CreateThread(
        0, 0, _Sec_DsObjPickerThread, in_PickInfo, 0, &lv_TID);
    }

    // failed?
    if (!in_PickInfo->hThread)
    {
      // cleanup
      Sec_DoneDsObjPicker(in_PickInfo);

      // return with error
       return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    }
  }

  // store parameter
  in_PickInfo->InitInfo = in_InitInfo;

  // set command code
  in_PickInfo->CmdCode = DSOPCMD_INITIALIZE;

  // trigger the thread to process the code
  SetEvent(in_PickInfo->hCmdEvt);

  // wait for result
  WaitForSingleObject(in_PickInfo->hRdyEvt, INFINITE);

  // return the result
  return in_PickInfo->hResult;
}

HRESULT Sec_InvokeDsObjPicker(TDsObjPicker *in_PickInfo, HWND in_hWnd, IDataObject **out_oData)
{
    /* locals */
    MSG lv_Msg;


  // thread not yet created?
  if (!in_PickInfo->hThread)
    return E_FAIL;

  // store parameters
  in_PickInfo->hWnd  = in_hWnd;
  in_PickInfo->oData = out_oData;

  // set command
  in_PickInfo->CmdCode = DSOPCMD_INVOKE;

  // trigger the thread
  SetEvent(in_PickInfo->hCmdEvt);

  // process messages of this thread while picker runs in other thread until event
  while (MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &in_PickInfo->hRdyEvt, 0, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT) != 0)
  {
    // get next message
    while (PeekMessage(&lv_Msg, 0,0,0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
      // translate/dispatch the message
      TranslateMessage(&lv_Msg);
      DispatchMessage(&lv_Msg);
    }
  }

  // return the result
  return in_PickInfo->hResult;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You asked why calling OleInitialize() first, followed by CoUnintialize and then reinit COM via CoInitializeEx works and is safe, look at the code of the rewritten OLE server in WINE, https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/dlls/ole32/ole2.c it comes pretty close to the "real thing". The OleInitialize calls CoInitializeEx itself with COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED and fails before doing the OLE-specific initializations upon a fail of CoInitializeEx. There is no reason to fail as the OLE code can run as well in MULTITHREADED mode. Remember MULTITHREADED means the caller must take care of synchronisation/locking while with APARTMENTTHREADED the COM libray will handle it for the code. So if you make sure you do not call the OLE code like dragdrop and clipboard at the same time from multiple threads then there is no problem. Keeping all UI in the main thread will do that. As you should already write multithreaded-aware code yourself using the requested MULTITHREADED mode.

I have the problem with directshow filters/drivers which lock the process when COM is initialized with APARTMENTTHREADED even when directshow is called from a thread with THREADED while the main UI thread runs in APARTMENTTHREADED.

Uninitializing COM after initializing OLE, then re-inititializing COM with MULTITHREAED during startup in the main UI thread makes you bypass the failure in OleInitialize. It is the best solution to make sure all runs well.

Comment: I have found a case where the combination of OleInitialize with COINIT_MULTITHREADED results in a crash: if IDsObjectPicker is invoked on a thread with this combination it will result in a crash when the dialog is closed and the object is released. In all windows versions (W2K, XP, Win10 tested). The stack will overflow in a recursive call of the same function.

Comment: Another issue is that when with the GUI main thread re-initialized to COINIT_MULTITHREADED, and a open filename common dialog is used with a hook, and in the Ok notification a message box is shown, the whole open filename dialog hangs. It does not happen if APARTMENTTHREADED is kept for the GUI thread.